# Angular Google Maps - Window wont open on click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a google map in my ionic app.

I am able to dynamically generate markers, but can't seem to bind infowindows.

```
$scope.arrayOfMarkers = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
    var user = results[i];
    var mySID = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("userObject")).userProfileId;
    if (user.userProfileId != mySID) {
        var userCoords = {
            latitude: user.userProfileLatitude,
            longitude: user.userProfileLongitude
        };
    var markerOptions = {
        animation: "drop"
    }
    var thisMarker = {
        id:i,
        coords: userCoords,
        options: markerOptions,
        idKey: i,
        window: {
            show: false,
            title: "Test"
        }
}
$scope.arrayOfMarkers.push(thisMarker);
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<ui-gmap-google-map id="map" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
                <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in arrayOfMarkers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options"  events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id" window="marker.window">                
                </ui-gmap-marker>
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

When I click the markers nothing happens. How should I be implementing window?

http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Comment: you are not bind `arrayOfMarkers`  to the scope `$scope`  
`$scope.arrayOfMarkers  = arrayOfMarkers;`

Comment: I looked at the documentation I wonder where from you use window directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `ui-gmap-window` directive inside the `ui-gmap-marker` and call a function on click of marker. in my example call function `toggleInfoWindow()` like `click="toggleInfoWindow()"`. it may help you

```
<ui-gmap-google-map id="map" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
     <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in arrayOfMarkers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" click="toggleInfoWindow()" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id" window="marker.window">  
           <ui-gmap-window options="windowOptions">
                <div>{{title}}</div> //your information here
            </ui-gmap-window>              
     </ui-gmap-marker>
 </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

In controller add `toggleInfoWindow` function:

```
$scope.toggleInfoWindow= function() {
     $scope.windowOptions.visible = !$scope.windowOptions.visible;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so so much you have saved my sanity!

Answer (score 1):

I looked at documentation did not found `window` directive 
but look what you can use

```
 <ui-gmap-windows show="{{window.show }}">
            <div ng-non-bindable>{{window.title}}</div>
 </ui-gmap-windows>
```

inside `ui-gmap-marker` to display window

you can refer to link [doc for window](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/window)